# Problems with EMail deliverability

Tags: debian, email, postfix, dovecot, spam-marked

I am having the following problem:
I am running a Debian server for about a year now, and I have never quite got emails to be delivered correctly. They keep getting caught in Googles Spam filters, Outlook doesn't even seem to bother and deliver them at all (not even to the spam folder, the logs say "250: Queued mail for delivery" though). By now I am really desperate, I have tried everything. SPF, DKIM and DMARC are set up and working correctly, as well as rDNS, TLS Encryption, and so on. I really don't know what I am doing wrong.
The content of the test emails I send varies from just "Test Email, please ignore" (most likely to be marked as spam) to excerpts from essays or other (successfully delivered mail, sent from my gmail account). Mail reputation testers like mail-tester.com or mxtoolbox reward me with a 100% score and no blacklist entries whatsoever. This is an example header from an email gmail has marked as spam:

```
Delivered-To: email@gmail.com
Received: by 10.13.219.204 with SMTP id d195csp864184ywe;
    Thu, 25 May 2017 12:21:05 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.223.168.120 with SMTP id l111mr23297935wrc.137.1495740065010;
    Thu, 25 May 2017 12:21:05 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1495740064; cv=none;
    d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    b=qfY69gpmb0GQn3ZGvSEJyIxi+zr2DbvUyY993tWQep9z+ZN0vEIzWjXyofJCBkSWH2
     sNutCeHIiMvfaloacvcMdWC5zoE/Pbf0TpEdNP+dnd+wXI112LXpVE+A8zA9MHoO0oEY
     CC7hfCzDRNP0IF6b//1euhzlJvrhuj99wWDBTcvKd1x/CWQJW1qNq1sMERmzYiQ1wHDM
     rnHbvkG385LihogIsdXhSZ4A93HCogl5ERUtr3+PT717pilkNUXZS4Hp6l8XFKXCOOnS
     /1oFR0xBY5FeZcJ6Vt/+C2H/qB7NtYNc0G3IVkTa6nmaxtihQqZHZ+e8NfVJX7BBWxn1
     nl/Q==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
    h=content-language:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:user-agent
     :date:message-id:subject:from:to:dkim-signature:dkim-signature
     :arc-authentication-results;
    bh=acCgJp9ry6elq8fVTxHxfBFnaouI4MAk66UPTSH2BW4=;
    b=Of8iF8mxuMrJZNYdVS+ni786ZuZNV7rnyLmz/bbu8O1StdBos4vAG8v2LaC3OFBvua
     OxD0EHbxbsMoIveVMF9pHXHI4bN5YD53t+x7hv9SYqCdCmyG1HCcMFFt6otL5PvSPVwK
     Q+beOiUjrp3TJ7btoSAWaPCdKSR41J39zTGrpowU/NYISQaUc5mt8Q4e2MHF/l6n9NRd
     bNvtXIqPUVAOvzDeV2YpNAOquFa33gSsXB3PvcsE6z1UkjPR7TSj0/W5E6uUMPV3BVy4
     tMOcjaEiuEY5a6qC+AxbaG5PUhWaCKhAJnai/Av0ypb05hikXnbECgbbWcm8r3PLuhyS
     TJpQ==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.de;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.de;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of mail@mydomain.de designates serverip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=mail@mydomain.de;
   dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.de
Return-Path: <mail@mydomain.de>
Received: from mail.mydomain.de (mail.mydomain.de. [serverip])
    by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id z35si25488994wrb.20.2017.05.25.12.21.04
    for <email@gmail.com>
    (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
    Thu, 25 May 2017 12:21:04 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of mail@mydomain.de designates serverip as permitted sender) client-ip=serverip;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.de;
   dkim=pass header.i=@mydomain.de;
   spf=pass (google.com: domain of mail@mydomain.de designates serverip as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=mail@mydomain.de;
   dmarc=pass (p=QUARANTINE sp=QUARANTINE dis=NONE) header.from=mydomain.de
Received: from localhost (mydomain.de [127.0.0.1]) by mail.mydomain.de (Postfix) with ESMTP id 476A7CA2F25 for <email@gmail.com>; Thu, 25 May 2017 21:21:04 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.de; s=mail; t=1495740064; bh=T6eVPXuCwCbaUltsFhuNXSvdEdHR+yNp0E88tVlLWVo=; h=To:From:Subject:Date:From; b=nG0IbgoWQ6jQGqZSE3YWPanvRkpLqKF/H4wIOMsQs3RBfxbFtJ1KKzFSgyvimgYTY
 PEz+43mX37Uce2QqGKbKnRTPObHYII6y/pFXHivSrAaAnQ87bpMT3c4WMPAaLOeWiQ
 kQnZb/UDNTrPlDVTmm/KcDP3LykKqdrPGMwOMBUA=
X-Virus-Scanned: Debian amavisd-new at mail.mydomain.de
Received: from mail.mydomain.de ([127.0.0.1]) by localhost (mydomain.de [127.0.0.1]) (amavisd-new, port 10024) with ESMTP id 3r4vvA1sDSP5 for <email@gmail.com>; Thu, 25 May 2017 21:21:03 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from [192.168.10.194] (pD92B27.dip0.t-ipconnect.de [myip]) by mail.mydomain.de (Postfix) with ESMTPSA id 9B621CA2F0B for <email@gmail.com>; Thu, 25 May 2017 21:21:03 +0200 (CEST)
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/simple; d=mydomain.de; s=mail; t=1495740063; bh=T6eVPXuCwCbaUltsFhuNXSvdEdHR+yNp0E88tVlLWVo=; h=To:From:Subject:Date:From; b=aXQ1tHoCs3oj/Q3TyHZ6eNnpWaaFoeTFKwgBw6TrLSubj8SptLnTQ5A2Avme/nAUA
 uEHeONftJ1VpKRIdK1aebBfMnPdoh6V9Qu1HLN4CaQTGKXHncGP8apoYaKxa61uRK+
 yzVW+JIHcXsUBOez5MoJ4JP8sSag9F/3k1vllqlo=
To: email@gmail.com
From: Tim Fuchs <mail@mydomain.de>
Subject: <Email subject>
Message-ID: <079da3e8-eb17-6f9f-2439-5d18a43f87d8@mydomain.de>
Date: Thu, 25 May 2017 21:21:03 +0200
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 
Thunderbird/52.1.1
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8; format=flowed
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Language: en-US

<Email message>
```

I cannot see anything which would make the email go to spam, maybe one of you can help.
It would be really great if i could finally get this resolved, as this has been bugging me for a really long time now...

Thank you very much for your help in advance ^.^

Comment: Your originating IP is 192.168.10.194? If so, that could be a problem since it appears to be a LAN address.

Comment: 192.168.10.194 is my local ip, I have replaced my outgoing Ip with 'myip' for security reasons

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your reply. Are you saying the originating IP is not 192.168.10.194, IOW, that's not actually in the real header? A non-reachable or LAN-addressed originating IP would be a reasonable spam indicator, so if you edited the headers for privacy (perfectly reasonable thing to do), you might want to make sure those edits don't themselves introduce spam markers....

Comment: Yes, this is in the actual header. However, since the server is not located in my local network and therefore cannot know my local ip, it must be thunderbird adding it to the headers. After researching a bit, this is perfectly normal and shouldnt introduce any problems, I will however set up postfix to remove it from the headers, not least because of privacy

Comment: Is Google Apps configured for the domain and has mail set up?

Comment: @JensErat What GoogleApps? I'm not using any Google Apps...